# How to ignore empty attributes within a composite component?

Tags: jsf, attributes, jsf-2, composite-component

How can i ignore empty attributes of a composite component?
Example:

```
<cc:interface>
<cc:attribute name="styleClass" />
<cc:attribute name="value" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
<h:inputText styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}"
    value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
    <cc:insertChildren />
</h:inputText>
</cc:implementation>
```

When i use the component by this:

```
<my:inputText />
```

It is rendered like this:

```
<input type="text" class="" />
```

How can i get an output without the empty class-attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
<my:inputText styleClass="myClass"/>
```

or you can set the default in your compoent:

```
<cc:attribute name="styleClass" default="myClass"/>
```

If you don't set the styleClass, then it is set to the default.